# URL amigable y paginación con Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

tengo el siguiente problema con Yii2

al agregarle

```
blog/<slug:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+>/'=>'blog/view',
```

las url del blog salen de esta forma:
**dominio.com/blog/titulo-noticia**

pero la paginación se muestra asi:
**dominio.com/blog/index?page=2&per-page=1**

y al darle click a la pagina 2 a me da el siguiente error

```
PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException
Attempt to read property "titulo" on null
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

web.php

```
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                'blog/<slug:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+>/'=>'blog/view',
                [
                    'class' => 'common\rest\UrlRule',
                    'controller' => [
                        'v1/pruebas',
                        'v1/registro',
                        'v1/acceso',
                        'v1/noticias',
                        'v1/contacto',
                        'v1/archivo',
                        'v1/categorias-noticia',
                        'publico/registro',
                        'publico/datos'
                    ],
                ]
            ],
            'class' => 'codemix\localeurls\UrlManager',
            'languages' => ['en', 'es'],    
],
```